# How to manage imports, dependencies in react component shared via npm

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, dependencies, shared-libraries

I'm new to sharing react components and I'd like to know if thing I want to do is even possible.

So I have a button component which changes the language of the app. I have an app which includes multiple react apps in it, and I'd like to share some of the components, this button for example.

```
import React from 'react';
import { useTranslation } from 'react-i18next';

const LngSwitch: React.FC = () => {
  const { i18n } = useTranslation();

  [...some other functions]

  return <div>[...component body]</div>;
};

export default LngSwitch;
```

The problem is that I'm using here this translation hook. I'd like the shared component to use the i18next package from the app it is installed in because otherwise it is useless.

I mean if I install and bundle "i18next" in my library directory and this bundle will be published, on importing this component in the app, it will have its own i18n config and that's not the point.

So I'd like my component to use the package installed in the app. I hope there is the way to achieve that. If not, maybe you have any idea how to share this component to make it work as it should.

Thanks

Comment: Can you add an `i18n` prop to your shared component, use the hook in each project/app that has a different translation set, and then pass in the unique data to your component?

Comment: You can also go the context route, store your i18n object in context, and fetch it using the context hook. If you put the context provider in the react tree for each app, that will also work

Comment: yes that's the option I'm considering to do, if it is not possible otherwise :<

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're likely looking for is a [peer dependency](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/configuring-npm/package-json#peerdependencies). You can add `react-i18next` to both your `devDependencies` and `peerDependencies`, and your `devDependencies` version will be used in development, while the `peerDependencies` version will take the package from the top-level `package.json` when used as a package.

That said, this may not be the best option in this context; peer dependencies are usually used with tightly coupled packages like plugins, and give you no control over what the package does besides specifying a version. Whether or not a peer dependency works here is dependent on the `react-i18next` implementation.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I think it is what I was lookin for. However I'll take your warning into consideration, thanks!